# bcrypt 'cb not a function' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bcrypt

(Assume the hashing has been done) I am trying to do an authenticate user function, by comparing an entered password and its hash in my MongoDB collection. This is my the method in my model.js (copied from the bcrypt guide):

```
PetOwnerSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};
```

And my controller.js:

```
exports.check = function (req, res) {
  var email = req.body['email'];
  var password = req.body['password'];

  PetOwner.findOne({ "email" : email}, 'email', function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    if ( task === null ){
      res.json(0); // no matching result
      console.log("Email is not yet registered");
    } else {

      task.comparePassword(password, task.password, function(err, isMatch) { //compare password and the already-hashed password in MongoDB
       if (err) throw err;

       if(isMatch){
           res.json(1);
           console.log("Found matching password to email");
       }
       else{
           res.json(0);
           console.log("Wrong password");
       }
      });   

    }
  })
};
```

And when I fetch the check method, the node console prompts the error that the cb in my model.js is not a function. I have tried several workaround but none has worked so far. Is there any way to debug this?

Comment: You are passing in too many arguments. `task.comparePassword(password, task.password, function(err, isMatch)` should simply be `task.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch)`. You get the value from the instance anyway with `this.password` inside the function.

Comment: FYI. You can shorten the code to `bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, cb);` because all you are doing in the wrapping function is passing arguments to `cb`. The `if (err)` parts belong in the implementing code, rather than the definition.

Comment: @NeilLunn If I remove task.password, how will it know what hash it should compare to?

Comment: `bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password` That's what I already told you. `this` means the current `task` instance you are calling the method on. So you don't need to pass it in again. Not only would it be pointless to do so, but your input is only expecting **one** other argument than the callback anyway. And that is all that is needed.

Comment: If I do what you suggested, it still prompts an error- 'data and hash arguments required.'

Answer (score 0):

```
PetOwnerSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb)
```

Your function takes a single parameter so you cannot refer to a context of "this" outside the function, like you do by using "this.password".

If you add the password to compare with as a second parameter like so:

```
PetOwnerSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, password2, cb)
```

You can then just compare the two inside the function as you are trying to do.

Hope it helps